# Python list max function when a list item is present

Tags: python

I was trying to find a max of element in a list but noticed something strange when the list contains another list item.

code.py

```
a=[[1,2],3,4]
max(a)
[1,2]
```

how does the max function works in the above works?

How does the list element is assumed as the max element...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, comparisons between incomparable types return a meaningless (but consistent) result:

```
>>> [1,2] > 3
True
```

`max` uses these comparisons to find the largest element, which in this case happens to be the list.

This [has been fixed](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) in Python 3, where you'd get:

```
>>> max([1,2], 3, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()
```

Comment: If it’s a consistent, i.e. deterministic, result, it’s not really random.

Comment: Perhaps you could extend this answer to explain the behavior as it will apply to the max() function?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Sorry, I thought that was obvious - `max` goes over the iterable, and compares each value with the current maximum. Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks; it isn't for my sake but I could imagine our Google viewers appreciating the connection.